# when we create pod, it has error that is Node did'n have enough resource: pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

when i create pod, it has error that is nodes didn't have enough resource:pods ,requested : 1, used : 0, capacity :0. But after 200ms, the other pod create successful. So i don't know the reason for the failure of the first pod.

Comment: Can you paste/show logs from dashboard?

Comment: I0328 02:28:48.477133 13957 kubelet.go:2094] SyncLoop (ADD, "api"): "pma-90bbb0b8-mh3s0"      \n  I0328 02:28:48.477277 13957 predicate.go:91] Predicate failed on Pod: pma-90bbb0b8-mh3s0, for reason: Node didn't hava enough resource: pods, requested:1, used: 0, capacity: 0

Comment: Can you also show me your pod config.yaml?

Comment: Which parameter do you want to see？

Comment: Can't understand why you have such a problem. Might be related to your pod configuration.